# SATA Hard Drive problems

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I have a 80GB IDE hard drive and few months back I bought a new 320GB SATA Hard drive.For almost two months everything worked perfectly but now suddenly I'm having problems in my SATA drive. When I try to copy or play something from the SATA drive after about 20 seconds the PC freezes and then comes back to the normal state. But all the SATA partitions are missing. Even when I go to the device manager and search it doesn't detect my drive.

So I took the drive for warranty but when they checked it worked perfectly and said that the drive is not defective. But when I fix it to my PC I'm still having that problem.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How old is the computer? Who is it made by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past, which was eventually due to a broken PSU. I see three possible causes:

1. Insufficient or irregular power from your PSU.
2. Malfunctioning disk controller on your motherboard. Perhaps a firmware update will resolve it, but it may be bad/broken hardware.
3. Broken SATA cable or motherboard connector. Try switching both the cable and the socket.

Comment: I see more of an issue with the PSU than anything else. I've have that problem when a PSU isn't supplying enough amps.

Comment: #3 was the culprit in making my Raptor drive operate at 1/3 of normal speed.  I thought if the flimsy SATA connector was loose it would either work or not work at all, but it did reduce the speed.  Changing to another SATA port "fixed" it.

Comment: I took my complete PC to repair. They said that the problem is because my windows is installed on the IDE im having this problem. Its weired..can something like that happen?

Comment: No, I've never heard of such a problem. You should be able to use IDE and SATA side-by-side without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try booting to a linux live CD. This will tell you a lot if everything work fine then there is only 2 options left Software or the HDD.IF you experience the same issue you will eliminate the possibility of a Software or failing HDD.

Comment: i ran my PC with Ubuntu and everything worked fine.. the only problem is with windows